# Calculated columns in SharePoint?

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I have 4 columns **Leave Type, PTO Available, Calculated days, Current PTO YTD.** **Leave Type is a drop-down box** which is having different types of leave like **casual leave, sick leave, marriage leave**.., like this.

And also **PTO Available** is the column which company gives some leaves for employee in a year like **casual leave in a year=18 days, Sick leave=10 days like that default holidays.**

And my **Calculated days** is the column which he will take leaves with **comparison of Start Date and Return Date,** which is a calculated column.

So,now my requirement is I have to take **Current PTO YTD has a calculated column** with different conditions like,

If **Leave Type=Casual Leave** then I have to **compare the field casual leave in PTO Available and I have to subtract the calculated days of that particular column and the result should be in Current PTO YTD in Current Casual Leave PTO YTD .**

Likewise, **if Leave Type=Sick Leave** the **I have to compare the field Sick leave in PTO Available, I have to subtract the calculated days of the particular column and the result should be in Current PTO YTD in Current Sick Leave PTO YTD.**

**And also I have to exclude Saturdays and Sundays in calculated columns?**

I have tried but no result. Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: can you share your formula that you have tried ?

Comment: That formula is wrong which i have used. So I removed that formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not try and built a complex formula in one go.

Take it step by step; make LeaveType="Casual Leave" work first..

You have already written down the pseudo code in your description,
Now... best done in Notepad.. rewrite the description into a Formula..

Once you think it might work, paste it into SharePoint... If it fails.. go back to Notepad..

Tip: copy paste each try as a new paragraph in Notepad.. you learn from reviewing previous mistakes.

```
If Leave Type=Casual Leave 
   then I have to compare the field casual leave 
       in PTO Available 
   and I have to 
       subtract the calculated days of that particular column 
and the result should be 
    in Current PTO YTD 
    in Current Casual Leave PTO YTD .
```

Notes:

- Calculated Columns can **not** set a value **in** another Column, you need a Workflow for that

  ```
  IF([Leave Type]="Casual Leave"
     ,"I have to compare the field casual leave"
     .....
  ```